# Convert seconds to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert seconds to `datetime`? I try this, but results are not correct:

```
CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(ms, dateTimeInSeconds, 0))
```

Here is an example: `1900-01-15 21:58:16.287` it's should be something like this `2010-11-02 14:56:50.997`

Comment: In what way is the result not correct?

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Please give an expected input and output. dateTimeInMilliseconds from when?

Comment: what datetime would dateTimeInMilliseconds 0 represent?

Comment: What value of dateTimeInMilliseconds is supposed to give you 2010-11-02 14:56:50.997?

Comment: 1288769335 milliseconds is about 14 days and 22 hours

Comment: There isn't some global standard that defines what a "datetime in milliseconds" means. The usual supplemental information provided is that it's going to be e.g. milliseconds since 1970-01-01, midnight UTC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given your example, try this:

```
select DATEADD(s, dateTimeInMilliseconds, '19700101')
```

Comment: It's still not correct, here is an example: 1970-01-16 08:47:36.533 -> 2010-..-..

Comment: what is the value that you have in milliseconds and what should be the result?

Comment: the results are with -2 hours, what must be change?

Comment: @VentsislavMarinov - I assume you're in a timezone that is 2 hours off from UTC?

Comment: @Guffa when he gave me the example I saw that was seconds and not milliseconds.

Comment: @VentsislavMarinov: So, the only piece of information about the date in the question that was certain, was actually wrong? ;) I have edited my answer according to your edit.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the value zero for date, this is converted to `1900-01-01`. Use the specific date that you have selected as epoch:

```
convert(datetime, dateadd(ms, dateTimeInMilliseconds, '2010-01-01'))
```

Note that the `datetime` data type doesn't have millisecond precision, the resolution is 1/300 second. If you for example have four milliseconds and convert it, you get `2010-01-01 00:00:00.003` rather than `2010-01-01 00:00:00.004`. If you need to preserve the millisecond resolution, you need to use the `datetime2` data type:

```
convert(datetime2, dateadd(ms, dateTimeInMilliseconds, cast('2010-01-01' as datetime2)))
```

#### Edit:

To use seconds instead of milliseconds, use `s` instead of `ms` in the `dateadd` call:

```
convert(datetime, dateadd(ms, dateTimeInSeconds, '1970-01-01'))
```

Comment: Is this the only way to solve the problem? If I don't know exact epoch ?

Comment: @VentsislavMarinov: You have to know the exact epoch. If you don't know that the value means, then it's impossible to convert it to something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Informative time span string:

```
declare @seconds int = 93825

convert(varchar,(@seconds/86400)) + 'd:' + format(dateadd(ss,@seconds,0),'HH\h:mm\m:ss\s')
```

Result: 1d:02h:03m:45s