# Find the time difference between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some 30000 rows in the table with the timestamp for every 10 mins and with some 20 columns.

```
timestamp  Col1 Col2 Col3 ... col20
```

`timestamp` would be like every 10 mins. ex: `18-05-2012 20:07`, `18-05-2012 20:17`, `18-05-2012 20:27`

Columns have integer or float data.

My question is: I need to find the gaps and time duration which the data has been not recorded in the columns. Suppose the column has Value, NULL, NULL, Value, Value, NULL. And it has the respective timestamps.

I need the output like as starttime and endtime of NULL values and duration (starttime - end time).

Comment: And what datatype does the `timestamp` column have??

Comment: the timestamp datatype is datetime ( example: 18-05-2012 18:28
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as I understood it now, you want the timedifference between the rows where in any column something was not recorded, right?

Then have a try with this:

```
SELECT
yt1.[timestamp] AS StartTime,
MIN(yt2.[timestamp]) AS EndTime,
DATEDIFF(s, yt1.[timestamp], MIN(yt2.[timestamp])) AS DifferenceInSeconds
FROM
yourTable yt1
LEFT JOIN yt2 ON yt1.[timestamp] < yt2.[timestamp]
WHERE
yt1.Col1 IS NULL
OR yt1.Col2 IS NULL
...
OR yt1.Col20 IS NULL
OR yt2.Col1 IS NULL
...
OR yt2.Col20 IS NULL 
GROUP BY yt1.[timestamp]
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if this works, since you didn't provide sample data to play around a bit.

To get the time difference in hh:mm:ss format search questions on stackoverflow, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031160/convert-seconds-to-datetime-in-sql-server).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i need the timestamp duration as well. For example, Col1 does not contains all NULL values, at some places it has not recorded, if we query as per your answer i will only get the timestamp and Col Null values, but i need duration between one timestamp to the second timestamp, if the value is null from 04-12-2012 2:00 to 04-12-2012 2:40 i need the time difference as 40 minutes with the timestamp of startime and endtime of null values. Nulll values are random, it can be in any row.. Please let me know if you are not clear. But realy appreacite your response

Comment: i tried the query, SELECT
DATEDIFF(s, yt1.[timestamp], MAX(yt2.[timestamp]) AS DifferenceInSeconds
FROM
EcstasyAggregateSignals yt1
LEFT JOIN yt2 ON yt1.[timestamp] > yt2.[timestamp]
WHERE
yt1.DBT IS NULL
 GROUP BY yt1.[timestamp] but i am getting error as Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Please help

Comment: @Reyaz It's a missing parantheses. Corrected it.

Comment: Thank you!! Query got executed but i did not get the expected result. i need something the output as StartTime| EndTime| Value Duration as columns and data should be like 18-05-2012 18:28|
18-05-2012 18:48| 20 minutes  ...... Here the timestamp column is increment for every 10minutes... Sorry if i am troubling you with confusion. Please let me know how to provide data.

Comment: You are genius.. Excellent.. i am done with the query. Great job.. if i have any issues will post here.. i am fan of stackoverflow from now..

Comment: Hi, On the same query that you had answered, the current output is like 18-05-2012 20:07,18-05-2012 20:17,18-05-2012 20:27,18-05-2012 20:37 etc are having 10 min gaps, consecutive gaps we should see 18-05-2012 20:07 as start time and 18-05-2012 20:37 as end time and gap in minutes 40. Can you please help

Comment: @Reyaz Post as new question please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 2 left joins: to detect the beginning of NULL appearance, in common my answer looks much like previous answer:

```
select distinct  max(table2.dt) as startTime, min(table3.dt) as endTime,  
datediff(minute, max(table2.dt), min(table3.dt)) as timeDifference
from Table_2 table1
left join Table_2 table2 on table2.dt < table1.dt 
left join Table_2 table3 on table3.dt > table1.dt
where (table3.tt1 is not NULL and table3.tt2 is not NULL)
  and (table2.tt1 is not NULL and table2.tt2 is not NULL)
  and (table1.tt1 is NULL or table1.tt2 is NULL)
  group by table1.dt, table1.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am confused with table2, table3.. i have only one table please if table name is ship and columns are DBT, LONG. can you please help me in rewriting the query. Thanks in advance

Comment: and the column name as timestamp