# Converting of the MySQL date stamp (milliseconds) to SQL server millisecond

Tags: mysql, sql-server, milliseconds

I have a date in MySQL: **1395774998**.  I understand this date is a number of milliseconds.

I used [epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert this date to:

```
**GMT: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 19:16:38 GMT**
```

I would like to convert this MySQL date to SQL Server without losing information.

Comment: You wan to convert the date to milliseonds or vice versa in Sql server?

Comment: Let say simple example, today date in sql server millisecond format 1395774998 like this, please look into that example given number is specific to today's date.

Comment: I think the date is actually in seconds (1395774998 is around 44.25 years - and base date is 1/1/1970) - AFAIK MySQL TimeStamp does not support milliseconds (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I need solution in SQL server, due to DB Migration

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031160/convert-seconds-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: @PaulF But according to my assumption, that is the diffrence between '01-01-1970' to till date in milliseconds, I may need to go with DATEDIFF function to find out exact millisecond.

Comment: (((1395774998 / 3600) / 24) / 365) = 44.25 (first div is to hours, next to days, next to approximate years)   1395774998 in milliseconds is only 387.7 hours or just over 16 days

Comment: But if you need milliseconds for sql-server multiply by 1000 - MySQL is only accurate to seconds

Comment: I hope I understand the original question - I made an honest attempt to edit and maintain the original intent.

Comment: What is the column's type and how are you doing the migration? If it is a date  type you wouldn't have to do such conversions - your MySQL provider would read it as a date/time and SQL Server's provider would store it as a datetime or datetime2 (whatever the target column's type is)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
DECLARE @Datetime BIGINT, @Result datetime, @LocalDatetime  BIGINT;

SET @Datetime = 1395774998
SET @LocalDatetime = @Datetime - DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
SET @Result = (SELECT DATEADD(second,@LocalDatetime , CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)))

select @Result
```

OR function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_ConvertUnixTimestampToDateTime (@Datetime BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LocalDatetime BIGINT
    SET @LocalDatetime = @Datetime - DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(second,@LocalDatetime, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)))
END;
```

Comment: Thanks@ Mega posting, I recently found one of the other solution and trying with same.